# Undefined method `visible=' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

help one companion in his project (I'm new to rails) and I want to remove this line, that would render validation errors

```
  redirect_to new_event_path, flash: { error: errors }
```

and she pulls the other error

```
undefined method `visible=' for nil:NilClass
```

how fix?

my create action this

```
def create
    success_message = "Событие успешно создано."
    if @user
      @event = @user.events.new(event_params)
    elsif params[:email].present?
      pass = SecureRandom.hex[0..10]
      unless @user = User.create(email: params[:email], password: pass, password_confirmation: pass)
        redirect_to new_event_path, flash: { error: @user.errors.full_messages.join("<br/>") }
      end
      sign_in(:user, @user)
      @user.send_temp_password(pass)
      @event = @user.events.new(event_params)
      success_message += " Вам на почту отправлено письмо с паролем. Ваш временный пароль: #{pass}. Сейчас Вы авторизованы в системе. Спасибо за участие в проекте!"
    else
      redirect_to new_event_path
    end
    @event.visible = true

    if @event.save      
      @event.assign_price!(params[:event][:price])
      @event.assign_types!(params[:event][:types_ids])
      @event.assign_days!(params[:event][:days])     
      redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user), flash: { success: success_message }
    else
      @event.event_dates.destroy_all
      errors = @event.errors.full_messages.join("<br/>")
      redirect_to new_event_path, flash: { error: errors }
    end


  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return when redirecting to terminate the further execution of same action:

```
redirect_to new_event_path
```

should be replaced by

```
return (redirect_to(new_event_path))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have @event undefined in the else estatement. So if something fails, the @event will be nil.

Just define @event inside the else statement.

```
  success_message += " Вам на почту отправлено письмо с паролем. Ваш временный пароль: #{pass}. Сейчас Вы авторизованы в системе. Спасибо за участие в проекте!"
else
  @event = Something
  redirect_to new_event_path
end
@event.visible = true
```